# Variable is undefined Make the variable optional in the blade template after using view composer

Tags: php, laravel-7

I've been trying to define a variable globally into my project (laravel 7). I need this variable be available in all views but i am getting following error:

```
$count is undefined
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $count }} with {{ $count ?? '' }}
```

First step i created a new service provider `TestSeriviceProvider`

Second step I added following line to `congif\app.php`

```
 App\Providers\TestServiceProvider::class,
```

Then i wrote following codes into `boot` method of `TestServiceProvider`

```
 public function boot()
    {

        View::composer('*', function ($view) {

            $view->with('count', 333);
        });
    }
```

Which part have i made mistake?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in the `boot()` method of the `AppServiceProvider`.

Just add `view()->share('count', 333);` and your `$count` is accessible on any blade page. If you have many shared data implemented, yes you can make a separate ServiceProvider for this. But keep in mind that your shared data may be overwritten in controllers.

Depending on the reason why you want to do this, you can look into a combination of middleware and the `session()` helper or combine shared variables in an array.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I already tried this method and it worked but i am looking for a solution that allow me to create my own ```ServiceProvider``` . I wonder if it safe to define global variables into ```AppServiceProvider```?

Comment: Sure it's safe. As you can see, every [Name]ServiceProvider extends the same base provider. In other words, it doesn't matter where you boot them. The only reason why you would make personal providers is to separate code. Just don't forget to register your providers in `config/app.php`. Although the providers are an integral part of the bootstrap sequence of Laravel, there is no security risk. It's not easy to understand how Laraval straps your facades, contracts and facades into the boot process. I still struggle with it sometimes. But it's worth your time to dig deeper.